# Understanding Partitioning in Hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to learn Hive and while referring the The Hadoop Definitive Guide, I had some confusions.

As per the text, partition in Hive is done by creating sub-directories of the same values of partitioning column. But as in Hive data loading simply means copying of files, and no data validation checks are done during loading, but during querying only, so does Hive check the data for partitioning. Or how does it determine which file should go to which directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or how does it determine which file should go to which directory?

It doesn't, you have to set the value of the destination partition in the `LOAD DATA` command. When you perform a `LOAD` operation into a partitioned table, you have to specify the specific partition (the directory) in which you are going to load the data by means of the `PARTITION` argument. According to the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables):

> The target being loaded to can be a table or a partition. If the table
>   is partitioned, then one must specify a specific partition of the
>   table by specifying values for all of the partitioning columns.

For instance, in [this example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-DMLOperations):

```
  hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './examples/files/kv2.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE invites PARTITION (ds='2008-08-15');
  hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './examples/files/kv3.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE invites PARTITION (ds='2008-08-08');
```

The two files will be stored in the `invites/ds=2008-08-15` and `invites/ds=2008-08-08` folders.